# How can I minimize inadvertently altering data without even noticing it?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I was testing a few SQL commands & at some point inadvertently erased data on one column.

1. What's the easiest way to retrieve it? 
   1.1.  Is it possible to retrieve a log of each command executed and its related output?
2. What best practices do you recommend to prevent inadvertently altering data without noticing it?

I luckily have a backup of the original data set, but am wondering if there isn't an alternative to re-starting from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

Make copy of the database and use that copy to test your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve erased data, except by restoring from a backup. If the database is small, then regularly dumping it (with `mysqldump`) can be enough.

[The `binlogs`](https://techjourney.net/how-to-read-mysql-binary-log-files-binlog-with-mysqlbinlog/) should record every command, with a timestamp. So you can see what happened in there. But only the command is recorded, not the output.

My recommendations for preventing this in the future...

1. Create a new login that only has `SELECT` permission, or whatever restricted range of permissions you want it to have, and use that for testing.
2. Don't play about on the live system. Do a `mysqldump` of your live database and restore the dump onto a test machine, then play there.

If the database is too big to dump, you can also create a read-replica of the live system and either use that for playing, or run the dump on that.

Note: keeping mysql replicas in sync can come with its problems.